# Getting indexOutOfBoundException from an endpoint

Tags: java

hi guys i am having been struggling to get my head around this, i dont know why i keep getting indexOutBoundsExpection, below are my code structures

service layer

```
public CompanyExprience getExperience(User user) {

CompanyExpirience model = new CompanyExpirience();

Long teamXp = (user.getTeams() == null ? 0L : 
((user.getTeams().get(0).getLevel() * 1000) + user.getTeams().get(0).getExperience()));

Long individualXp = ((user.getLevel() * 1000) + user.getExperience());
        model.setIndividualLevel(user.getLevel());
        model.setTeamLevel(user.getTeams() == null ? 0L : user.getTeams().get(0).getLevel());
        model.setTeamStatus(toStatus(user.getTeams() == null ? 0L : user.getTeams().get(0).getLevel()));
        model.setIndividualStatus(toStatus(user.getLevel()));
        model.setIndividualExperience(((individualXp * 100) / 100000));
        model.setTeamExperience(((teamXp * 100) / 100000));
        model.setTeamExperiencePoint(user.getTeams() == null ? 0L : ((user.getTeams().get(0).getLevel() * 1000) + user.getTeams().get(0).getExperience()));
        model.setIndividualExperiencePoint((user.getLevel() * 1000) + user.getExperience());

        return model;

    }
```

and below is my  my endpoint

```
@GET
    @Path("/compexpirience")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ExperienceModel getExperience() {


    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();

        return activityService.getExperienceModel(user);
}
```

can someone try to explain to me why google chrome and eclipse stack trace are giving me indexOutBoundsException, i know what normally cause that error with this one i am struggling

Comment: *where* (what line) are you getting that

Comment: Your controller doesn't call the method you showed us, it calls `getExperienceModel` .

Comment: yes you are correct i just typed wrong sice i didnt do copy and paste

Comment: @GET
 @Path("/compexpirience")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public ExperienceModel getExperience() {
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
  
  return activityService.getExpirince(user);
 }

Comment: Long teamXp = (user.getTeams() == null ? 0L : ((user.getTeams().get(0).getLevel() * 1000) + user.getTeams().get(0).getExperience()));

Comment: that the line giving error

Comment: Check that `!user.getTeams().isEmpty()` .

Comment: so should i set it an initial value?

Comment: hi Guys based on the question i posted yesterday will th this help..   Long teamXp = (user.getTeams() == null ? 0L: user.getTeams().isEmpty()? 0L : user.getLevel() * 1000);